# How to collect a limited number of nodes using Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I want to perform a `MATCH` query on the top 25 results of a previous `MATCH`, how would I do this in Cypher?

My first query is like:

```
START inputMovie=node(0)
MATCH (inputGenre:Genre)-[:IS_GENRE]-(inputMovie:Movie)
WITH inputMovie, COLLECT(inputGenre) AS inputGenres
MATCH (genre:Genre)-[o:IS_GENRE]-(outMovies:Movie)
WITH inputGenres, outMovies, genre
WHERE (genre IN inputGenres)
RETURN outMovies.title, count(genre) AS foo
ORDER BY foo desc
LIMIT 25
```

How would I then perform a MATCH query on *only* those 25 results? Can I collect a number of nodes? `COLLECT(m)` would collect every single node matching the `WHERE` constraint. Is there a way to collect the top 25 from a `MATCH` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

First of all, your current query can be improved. The following shorter and faster query should be equivalent (and avoids using the deprecated `START` clause):

```
MATCH (outMovie:Movie)-[:IS_GENRE]-(:Genre)-[:IS_GENRE]-(inputMovie:Movie)
WHERE ID(inputMovie) = 0
MATCH (outMovie)-[:IS_GENRE]-(genre:Genre)
RETURN outMovie.title, count(genre) AS foo
ORDER BY foo DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

In general, you can replace `RETURN` with `WITH` if you want to extend an existing query. You just have to provide an alias for returned values that do not already have an identifier (in your case, `outMovies.title` would need to be aliased).

Here is a simple example with your query:

```
MATCH (outMovie:Movie)-[:IS_GENRE]-(:Genre)-[:IS_GENRE]-(inputMovie:Movie)
WHERE ID(inputMovie) = 0
MATCH (outMovie)-[:IS_GENRE]-(genre:Genre)
WITH outMovies.title AS title, count(genre) AS foo
ORDER BY foo DESC 
LIMIT 25
RETURN COUNT(title) AS num_titles;
```

The returned `num_titles` will be at most 25.

Comment: thanks for this. I'm no longer using `START`. however, as movies have multiple genres I have to collect them and use the `WHERE (genre IN inputGenres)` line.

Comment: I do accept, I just didn't get around to testing your answer until now.